# Select from table and keep all lines with a certain column value in the bottom of the result

Tags: java, sql, jpa, repository

I have the following table:

| name | age |
| --- | --- |
| pedro | 11 |
| duda | 12 |
| joao | 7 |
| pedro | 9 |
| guga | 10 |
| pedro | 13 |
| zelda | 10 |

What I want is to select all entries here in which `age >= 10`, but at the same time keep all results which `name = pedro` in the last position, like this:

| name | age |
| --- | --- |
| duda | 12 |
| guga | 10 |
| zelda | 10 |
| pedro | 11 |
| pedro | 13 |

So there are two questions:

1. is it possible to do it with a select statement?
2. if so, is it possible to do this with JPA Repository simply naming a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to do it with a select statement?

Yes you can use `where` and `order by` with `case` like:

```sql
select *
from table
where age >= 10
order by case name when 'pedro' then 2 else 1 end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE WHEN` in the `ORDER BY`

> ```
> SELECt * FROM tab1
> WHERE age >= 10
> ORDER BY CASE WHEN `name` = 'Pedro' THen 2 ELSE 1 END ASC, `name` ASC, `age` ASC
> ```
>
> ```
> name  | age
> :---- | --:
> duda  |  12
> guga  |  10
> zelda |  10
> pedro |  11
> pedro |  13
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1f803ba057e0987201052c78690c61f2)*

Comment: I think better would be `case name when`.

Comment: only if he wants to sort more names at the bottom, but that wasn't the question here